# how to restrict the country based move to pin on location in MKMapkit

Tags: swift, mkmapview, autocompletetextview, autosuggest

I use MKMapkitView when I move the map location based on the lat,long it's pick the address on the textfield. Now I need to change to Only India based search on the map how to restrict it. any one help me. my code is [dropbox.com/s/rt9rdt3x164ghbo/LocationVC.swift?dl=0][1] any one help me. No idea for me.

Comment: mapKit is picking address from textField , So when user search before sending the Values to mapKit just make a check by exploring if that lat, Lon or location is related to India , just a Try

Comment: hi iOS Geek how to restrict the search on the text field. this is my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/rt9rdt3x164ghbo/LocationVC.swift?dl=0